# Spring Boot Unit testing with Mockito and Junit 5, How do I set password to user

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have the following test classes to create a mock user and check service that changes users passwords, but somehow when I initialize the user object password is always null.

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {

   @Mock UserRepository userRepository;

   @Mock ApiUtil apiUtil;
   @Mock PasswordEncoder passEncoder;
   @Mock EmailService emailService;

   @InjectMocks UserServiceV1 userService;
   @InjectMocks FakeUUIDProvider provider;
   @InjectMocks BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt;

   User user1;

   @BeforeEach
   public void setUp() {
     this.user1 = new User(
       this.provider.uuid(), 
       "username1", 
       "email1", "password1", 
       "displayName1", true
     );
   }

   @Test
   void shouldChangeUserPassword() throws Exception {

      // Stub
      when(this.userRepository.findByUsernameOrEmailAndIsActiveTrue(
        this.user1.getEmail(), this.user1.getEmail()))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(this.user1));

      // Action
      final var retrivedUser = this.userService.forgotPassword(this.user1.getEmail());

      log.info(this.user1.getPassword());
   }
}
```

The **retrivedUser** object has all the other field values but password, the password field is always null. I have tried Mock creating PasswordEncoder and BycryptPasswordEncoder, but still no luck.

The expected result would be user1 having a password with the value "passsword1" not null;

Comment: Sure that `forgotPassword` doesn't set it to null? Otherwise there's not enough information in your posting to answer your question. No clue what ``forgotPassword` actually does, for example.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz no it doesnt it just changes current password to another random string hehe, i have also tried to set it directly just before calling toString() method still same

Comment: Without the cod if User, and forgotPassword, etc. it will be hard to do anything instead of just guessing wildly. I assume a good debugging would also help...